# How to force a textbox to "changed" even if user has not typed anything. Value set from nsIFilePicker

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am working on a XUL Firefox extension. One of my windows is an "options" preferences window which includes a `textbox`. The `textbox` is supposed to contain a file path. I am using a button and `nsIFilePicker` to let the user select the file. The text in the box is updated but the change is never reflected in the extensions preferences. It only works if the user types directly inside the `textbox`. Is there any way to "force" the change to be applied even if the change was not made using the keyboard?

```
onPrivKeyBtn: function() {
  const nsIFilePicker = CI.nsIFilePicker;
  var fp = CC["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
  fp.init(window, "Select File", nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
  fp.appendFilters(nsIFilePicker.filterAll|nsIFilePicker.filterXML);
  if (fp.show() != nsIFilePicker.returnCancel) {
    var file = fp.file;
    var path = fp.file.path;
    document.getElementById("privKeyBox").value = path;
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, it is a preferences window. So I checked that the preference is updated when typing directly into the textbox. It only has problems when the change is done by the `onPrivKeyBtn` function.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, textbox ````privKeyBox```` is in ````prefpane````?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set [`<preference>.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/preference) instead of setting the value of the textbox.

Alternatively, the [`<prefpane>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/prefpane) has a `userChangedValue(elem)` method.

Lastly, you could fire a `change` event (`.createEvent()`, `textbox.dispatchEvent()`) yourself, but that is equal to calling `.userChangedValue(elem)`.